# UICollectionView borderline not present with black background

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm using a uicollectionview for develope a crossword, when I try to fill black cell I don't see the border line.
My code is:

```
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell setFrame:CGRectInset(cell.frame, 3.0f, 3.0f)];``
    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:3];
```

This is the result:

[image]
How to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the frame of the cell by placing it down and to the left by 3 on x and 3 on Y because of this line:

```
[cell setFrame:CGRectInset(cell.frame, 3.0f, 3.0f)];
```

Maybe you should add a subview to the cell that is black and assign it a frame like this

```
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(3,3, cell.frame.size.width-6, cell.frame.size.height-6)];
```

So in total i think it would look something like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,3, cell.frame.size.width-6, cell.frame.size.height-6)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[view.layer setCornerRadius:3];
[cell addSubview:view];
```

Comment: I've just tried this solution and work the first time, the problem is if I click on cell with number, I reload the uicollecollection view with this code:

[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
    } completion:nil];

and I don't why, but the black cell increase. I've put a lot of log and the array is read well.

Comment: I saw your code but i think i'm missing a part of it because where and how do you create the collectionview cell? Do you use different cell identifiers for each type of cell? It looks to me when the collection view gets reloaded he uses cell that already exists but shuffles them a bit around.

Comment: Problem soleved. I've added this 2 lines after uiview definition: 
[cell.backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
cell.backgroundView = view;

Comment: That is good to hear! Good luck with finishing your game! And can you mark my anwser as correct for the first problem you had?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([strArrayLabel isEqualToString:@"black"])
        {
            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,3,    cell.frame.size.width-6, cell.frame.size.height-6)];
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [view.layer setCornerRadius:3];
            [cell addSubview:view];

            NSLog(@"black");
        }
        else if ([strArrayLabel isEqualToString:@"blank"])
        {
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [[cell myLabel]setText:number];
            [[cell letter]setText:letter];

            NSLog(@"blank");
        }
        else
        {

            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [[cell myLabel]setText:number]; 
            [[cell letter]setText:letter]; 

            NSLog(@"no black no blank %@, <%@>", number, letter);
        }
}
```

[image]

[image]